# STATICFILES_DIRS pointing to remote server without being collected -IIS with WSGI Handler

Tags: python, django, iis

I have a view that is loading a table of elements from an SQL server database to show a list of invoices from system. these invoices files are located in a shared network drive.
right now in my development environment I'm able to do a runserver and use my website as I want.
The proble comes when I deploy in a IIS Server (production) since I need to now provide these files from the same remote serve and I have the problem that my staticfiles_dirs is not being resolved.

Right now I have:

```
> STATIC_URL = '/static/' STATICFILES_DIRS =
> ['//SharedDrive/folder/folder',]
```

and my home.html is doing a `{%load static%}`

where later I reference the path using `{% static %}`

the problem is that this works in my local machine, but not deployed.

how can I make it work without having to move this content to my django server? (since the data is over 400gb)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't serve static files in production. You have to deploy Django app on a WSGI compatible server like Apache or Nginx.

Comment: can you explain this a little more please? instead of IIS I should use apache for example? this would work for serving my files that are on a shared drive?  would you recommend Apache or Nginx for ease of implementation?

Comment: @Baldie47 I recommend using nginx because it's very easy to deploy python applications with it. Also nginx can serve static content much faster than apache. Apache's syntax also looks very old

Comment: @Baldie47 I second this